# Weird grey tint in top right of screen on navigation segue

Tags: ios, animation, navigation, segue

I have a strange, unwanted graphic effect when I navigate to and from views. There is a temporary grey tint in the top right of the screen. As it's difficult to describe, I made a short screen capture of what is happening.

View it here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JL05q3dp0n4&feature=youtu.be

I was just curious if any of you have seen this and/or know where I can look to modify/get rid of this behavior?

Thanks so much,

Jared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. It had to do with my navigation bar being translucent and one of my covered background layers being grey. I checked off 'Translucent' on my navigation bar and it fixed it.

[image]